# How to review a paper for originality?

Tags: publications, peer-review

Originality with timeliness is among the most important criteria for a paper to get published.

Many a times when we are reviewing a paper, we are faced with dilemma as to how much of it is original, how much of it is based on another paper, and how much of it is just repetition in a slightly different context. Also, at times papers cater to interdisciplinary and cross-area and it may seem that the idea is original.

1. What preparation does the reviewer need to have in order to review a paper justly?
2. How do you judge the originality of a paper?

Comment: One tip which you may find useful: I have found that often, the closest existing work to the reviewed manuscript is the authors' previous work. So by reading the authors' previous work you can see whether they have made a large advancement or a small increment.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

I've reviewed more than 50 papers, and my preparation to review them has varied widely.  At least a few of them have drawn heavily on papers I've written.  Generally, these are extending my results.  Typically, I ask myself: **What does this paper add?** Is it something I would have thought of easily or not?  If yes, why didn't I include it in my paper?

In contrast, I've also **reviewed some papers that I was not well prepared for.**  They were in my general field, but in a subarea that I hadn't worked in.  **These papers took a lot more work.** (**Up to 10x as long** for me to review as a paper in an area where I'm very familiar.)  For papers in an area that's new to me, I often have to look up (and skim) at least a few of the references from the introduction to judge whether the paper is original.  **Originality has at least two very different levels**.  The easier one to achieve is: (1) this **result is new**, and doesn't follow simply from anything previous.  The much harder one is, (2) this **technique is fundamentally new** and produces interesting results.  If the results are interesting, most journals are happy to publish articles of type (1).  Articles of type (2) are much rarer, and can potentially open entire new fields.

**tl;dnr:**

1. ***Preparation***: you need to *either* know the subarea well *or* be willing to read a lot to learn about it.
2. ***Originality***: What papers does it draw on? How likely is it that a reader of those would be able to write this paper?  Answering this question may require you to read a lot of background.

Comment: Why would you agree to review papers in an area new to you?

Comment: First, let me clarify that it was usually a *subarea* that I had not done research in, although I had often heard a lecture on something related before.  Typically I said yes because I either wanted to learn more about that area or the work of that specific author, or because I wanted to get experience refereeing for that particular journal (similar to the reasons I would opt to teach a new class in an area I didn't know that well yet).